# Cache complex directives in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I am working on a project targeting mainly mobile devices.
The app receives a list of different objects from the server which shall be rendered all at once.
Each object type has it's own directive, which takes care of business logic. But because most objects share certain features we created 'sub-directives' which work as mixins to keep it DRY.

If more than just a handful of those objects should be displayed (which is the default case), Angular takes quite some time parsing and instantiating those directives + sub-directives.

Our performance improvements so far:

- replaced the ng-repeat with a custom directive, which also works like an infinite-scroll
- use bindonce to limit bindings only where they are really necessary
- pre-fill the $templateCache with the templates, instead of fetching
  them via templateUrl

But even with those improvements, the performance is still not acceptable. (Especially when navigating to the state containing the list)

The approach I have in mind now is as follows:

1. let Angular fully parse and create one such directive with its
   sub-directives
2. cache the resulting node
3. if we have another object of the same type simple reuse it and link    it with a new Scope

But even after going through Angulars source code I have no clue where I could hook in to receive the finished result before advancing to the next object in the list.

So far it parses the template of the actual directive for each entry in the list, then comes back and finishes the sub-directives.

Hope I was able to make it understandable what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In my custom ngRepeat-like directive I used the $cacheFactory to cache compiled elements: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$cacheFactory.Cache

Comment: Caching is not the problem, the timing is. I want to cache the resulting node-tree after the first directive has been completely layed out (doesn't matter if it's linked up or not), so the next objects can re-use it instead of doing all the work again.